# Disable Visual Studio Special Debugging Features

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am new to Visual Studio, so I am used to IntelliJ and Eclipse style of functioning. I usually do not use a debugger when I develop, so I do not want to use it in Visual Studio too.

Is it possible to disable all special debugging functionalities which Visual Studio provides when you start your application? I want to have only normal output for the errors. When I disable all debugging, then I do not have usual output too, so this is not an option.

I tried many settings, but nothing seems to work and give me the results I want - no extra popup windows, no shiny layout changes when you have an error, just ordinary output.

Thanks!

Comment: Does Ctrl-F5 do what you're asking?

Comment: @SurvivalMachine No, with Ctrl+F5 all debugging output is disabled, so I do not have a stacktrace in the console, which I need.

Comment: the console in visual studio is directly tied to the debugger.

Comment: @DanielA.White So it is impossible, to have only stacktrace without debugger?

Comment: well your program can output it somewhere when an exception is thrown or a stack trace object is created.

Comment: @DanielA.White Okay... Very unfortunate.. Could you please form an answer, so I can select it as a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone's definition of "normal output" is different. Personally, I like the way Visual Studio handles debugging.

The console window in Visual Studio is a debugger feature and hence that is why it doesn't work when it's not attached to the process. If you want a stack trace without attaching, you could use your language/framework's built-in facilities such as an `Exception` or `StackTrace` in the case of .NET. You could also have Windows write a crash dump, but then you are debugging the corpse inside of Visual Studio.